# PM2 list return an empty list

Tags: amazon-ec2, npm, pm2

We are using a AWS CodeDeploy and PM2 `version: '^0.12.14'` to manage our web application, but we got a empty list after hitting `pm2 list` although that node application is started successfully and `PM2` is running currently on the server, Also `PM2` logs are working fine for both the application logs and PM2 logs `~/.pm2/pm2.log` as following:

`Starting execution sequence in -cluster mode- for app name:app id:0
App name:app id:0 online`

but when we tried to show the application `app` details it shows that there is no app with this name or even id `pm2 show app`, it gives us `[PM2][WARN] app doesn't exist`.

We don't know what's exactly the problem, could you please help us?

Here is a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/1508)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with `pm2 0.12.x` and i thought an update should fix that but unfortunately not, I got the same issue using the version `1.1.3`

Then i start trying to reproduce this using `docker`.
I created a docker container with ssh config and run this as an ssh server where i deployed my application. I couldn't reproduce the issue.

Comparing the environment variables of both servers (my live server and the server running in docker), i found that the only difference was the `PM2_HOME` variable, when i unset the PM2_HOME variable on my live server, i could list again my running applications using `pm2 list`
I think the PM2 home folder is by default `~/.pm2` my `PM2_HOME` was the home folder of the user.
So my solution was either unsetting the env variable or setting it to the right folder, in my case was this `/home/username/.pm2`

Here is an example `Dockerfile` with node, npm & pm2 where you can deploy your app and compare to you server configs:

```Dockerfile
FROM node:latest

apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:root' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin without-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login 
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

RUN npm install -g pm2@1.1.3

EXPOSE 22
```